# Add complete folder to scripts section of angular-cli.json

Tags: json, typescript, angular-cli, angular5

I have a shared folder (symlink) with typescript files (.ts), which I want to them to be built and added to my dist-folder afterwards.

If I put every single file-name to the scripts section in my 'angular-cli.json' like this:

```
... 
"scripts": [
        "app/shared/Scripts.Shared/IConstructableFromString.ts",
        "app/shared/Scripts.Shared/User.ts"
      ],
...
```

It works.
But when I try to add the complete folder like this:

```
... 
"scripts": [
        "app/shared/Scripts.Shared/**"
      ],
...
```

The following error occures:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\project\src\app\shared\Scripts.Shared\**'
```

**My question:**

Is it possible to add a complete folder (e.g. with wildcards '*') or is there another solution?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel